# How do I run this query?

Tags: ms-access

Some background information:
I have one database online, and the other is hosted locally.

Each database has a table of products with ID's that correspond to each other. For the sake of the example they can both be called product_id
The local database has a checkbox that says "on internet", the field is just called OnInternet.

The situation. I'm trying to run a query that will list all product_id's where OnInternet is "no"

When I try to run the query, it just shows the same product.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the query you are currently trying to use as well as any VBA or Macro code you are using.